# Measure and empty set second version

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

If A is a nonempty open set, the measure of A is not 0 ...first open set is uncountable, I pick up one interval irrational intersect [ 0,1 ] with measure 1 ...however this is not open...I am wondering is this statement true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: As $A$ is nonempty and open, there is some open intervall $(a, a+\epsilon) \subseteq A$. Hence $\mathbb R = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb Z} (A + \frac{n\epsilon}2)$. Now $\lambda(A + \frac{n\epsilon}2) = \lambda(A)$. Conclude that $\lambda(A) > 0$ by using countable subadditivity.

Comment: So this statement is true right?

Comment: Yes, it is. ${}$